# What is the best way to annoymise an email address in a Magento Order

Tags: magento2, customer, gdpr

We have been been asked to remove all customer data from our systems - easy on Linnworks - seems impossible in Magento

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to anonymise the email in the order data, you can do so with a mysql query like so.

```sql
UPDATE sales_order SET customer_email = 'anonymized@email.com' WHERE customer_email = 'original@email.com';
```

Although this doesn't account for all their other personal information (addresses, payment data etc).

If you want to go through manually and remove/anonymise all their personal data you can work from the data references in the DevDocs

https://devdocs.magento.com/compliance/privacy/pi-data-reference-m2.html#database-entities

But the most scaleable / quickest solution to handle this would be to opt for a module thats already provides this functionality.

https://github.com/opengento/magento2-gdpr

https://amasty.com/gdpr-for-magento-2.html

Answer (score 1):

Backup your database and then run below sql query on database to remove all customer data.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_grid_flat`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_log`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_visitor`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `persistent_session`;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```